# Correct way for updating the yeoman generator and re-publishing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, generator, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I have successfully created yeoman generator following the documentation and published as well. So, the same generator is being used across many projects to kick start.

> **My question is:** If we update the main generator, Is there any way the
>   projects which are already in use get the latest update? How to best
>   deal with this approach. Is yeoman feasible with this? or we need to
>   load it as an npm dependency package with versions?

Looking forward to reference links to understand with and without yeoman to handle for future updates across projects